# if the maximum capacity of character is 256 how to store character array of 1000?

Tags: c, character

If the maximum capacity of character is 256 how to store **character array** of 1000?
is it possible to declare:
    char s[1000];

Comment: Yes, it is possible to declare `char s[1000];`.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum capacity"?

Comment: A typical `char` may have 1 of 256 values.  The number of elements in an _array_ can range `[1...SIZE_MAX)`.

Comment: @tarun Gupta You probably on confusion between limit app architect and memory storage :  when you create an static array, is going to storing on the stack in the PE .data/ .rdata /.bss sections of your binary. A dynamically array when you use new, malloc ...  will be allocated directly on the heap.

Comment: The number of values that can be stored in a single character has no bearing on how large an array of characters can be.  It isn't as though C uses the first byte of a string to store the length of the string. (Some languages, such as Pascal, do use that sort of trick in some implementations.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is certainly possible.

```
char s[1000];
```

You can think of 1000 as the "length" of the array and 256 as the "width".  You get an array of 1000 `char`s.  Each `char` is 8 bits (on the machine you're using, at least), and can therefore store 256 distinct values.  (And, actually, it would probably be more appropriate to think of the "width" as being 8, not 256.)

Here is your array, with each box representing one `char`:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
s: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | ... |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7        999
```

Or here it is showing the individual bits:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
s: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |     |   | 7
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |     |   | 6
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |     |   | 5
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |     |   | 4
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+    bit
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | ... |   | 3  number
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |     |   | 2
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |     |   | 1
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |     |   | 0
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7        999
                array index
```

Suppose we put a string in the array, either by calling `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(s, "Hello!");
```

or my initializing it when we declare it:

```
char s[1000] = "Hello!";
```

By bytes it looks like this:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
s: | H | e | l | l | o | ! |\0 |   | ... |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7        999
```

Or by bits it looks like this:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
s: | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   |     |   | 7
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |   |     |   | 6
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |   |     |   | 5
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   |     |   | 4
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+    bit
   | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |   | ... |   | 3  number
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |   |     |   | 2
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |   |     |   | 1
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
   | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |   |     |   | 0
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-   -+---+
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7        999
                array index
```

And there are 993 spaces in the array left over.

[P.S. to nitpickers: Yes, those are ASCII codes, and no, character encoding is not specified by the C Standard.  But I think we can safely assume that those are the codes the questioner would see.]

Comment: Nitpicking: how can you be *sure* that the OP is using ASCII and not e.g. UTF-8 ? I guess -from his name or pseudo- he might not be American so is more likely (than US citizens) to use UTF-8 instead of the obsolete ASCII. See http://utf8everywhere.org/ ; in 2017 ASCII is not very common and most computers are using UTF-8

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch When I wrote that I was worried about EBCDIC nitpickers, not UTF-8 nitpickers.  And of course the encoding of the example string I chose is identical in both ASCII and UTF-8.  But I suppose I'll have to fix that last sentence... done.

Answer (score 2):

The 256 is the number of values in a single `char` (which is often an 8 bits byte, and 256 = 2<sup>8</sup>).

<sup>(caveat, the C11 standard allows wider `char`-s, e.g. of 32 bits; but this is *very uncommon*)</sup>

A string is an array or a memory zone containing several `char`-s, and conventionally terminated by a zero byte.

You can have very big strings, notably using [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). For instance, on *some* computers

```
 char*hugestring = malloc(1000000000);
```

can succeed. Then you could fill that billion-bytes string. On many computers, that `malloc` call would fail, and you *always* need to check the result of  `malloc`, at least by following the above line with

```
if (!hugestring) { perror("malloc hugestring"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

If you use [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), don't forget to later call [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) (you need to have *conventions* about who is responsible for that); otherwise you have a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). BTW the [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html), [strdup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) and [open_memstream](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html) functions are very useful (but not available everywhere) to conveniently build dynamically allocated strings (internally `malloc` is used by them). Tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) are helpful to help detecting memory leaks.

You can also have arrays. If they are [local variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) (a.k.a. [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)) they generally sit in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (unless the compiler optimized for them).

For example, using [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to safely fill a local buffer (without [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)),

```
char buffer[100];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "x=%d, name=%s", x, name);
```

but it is unreasonable to have large call frames, so a local array should generally be less than a few hundred bytes (or perhaps a few thousands of them). The entire call stack is generally limited to one or a few megabytes. Details are system specific.

Be aware of [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) issues. In 2017 read at least [utf8everywhere.org](http://utf8everywhere.org/) and about [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).... so think of `char` as a byte (since some [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) characters need *several* bytes, so take *several* `char`-s to be represented, hence on my Linux desktop `strlen("être")` is 5 and `sizeof("être")` is 6 since the accentuated `ê` letter is UTF-8 encoded in two bytes). You might use some library like [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/).

Look also into some [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misinterpret what you refer to as "capacity" of a `char`. `char` is an 8-bit value, which means it can range anywhere from `0000 0000b ()` to `1111 1111b (255)`.

This only refers to one individual value. This means you can write `char c = 20;`, but not `char c = 1000;`.

As such, this means that there are 256 different possible values for a single `char`.

---

Arrays are a different concept: An array stores multiple values of one specific type - such as an array of characters.

To answer you question: Yes, you can store 1000 `char` values in an array, like `char s[1000]` as Steve Summit suggested.

Naturally, if you have 1000 chars, this will mean there will be duplicates (since there are only 256 unique characters possible).