# What causes a char to be signed or unsigned when using gcc?

Tags: c, gcc

What causes if a `char` in C (using gcc) is signed or unsigned? I know that the standard doesn't dictate one over the other and that I can check `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX` from limits.h but I want to know what triggers one over the other when using gcc

If I read limits.h from libgcc-6 I see that there is a macro `__CHAR_UNSIGNED__` which defines a "default" char signed or unsigned but I'm unsure if this is set by the compiler at (his) built time.

I tried to list GCCs predefined makros with

```
$ gcc -dM -E -x c /dev/null | grep -i CHAR
#define __UINT_LEAST8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define __CHAR_BIT__ 8
#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 0x7fffffff
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR32_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __SCHAR_MAX__ 0x7f
#define __WCHAR_MIN__ (-__WCHAR_MAX__ - 1)
#define __UINT8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define __INT8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_WCHAR_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __CHAR16_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define __INT_LEAST8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR16_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 4
#define __INT_FAST8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __CHAR32_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __UINT_FAST8_TYPE__ unsigned char
```

but wasn't able to find `__CHAR_UNSIGNED__`

Background: I've some code which I compile on two different machines:

**Desktop PC:**

- Debian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch)
- gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18)
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4150
- libgcc-6-dev: 6.3.0-18
- `char` is signed

**Raspberry Pi3**:

- Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch)
- gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1)
- ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
- libgcc-6-dev: 6.3.0-18+rpi
- `char` is unsigned

So the only obvious difference is the CPU architecture...

Comment: ...and we have in a nutshell why chars should not be used.

Comment: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714). Most modern implentations will have signed char although you can change that with an option. One notable exception is ARM, due to [performance reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20576301/995714)

Comment: It seems on Linux at least it's pretty much a 50/50 split between signed and unsigned. https://wiki.debian.org/ArchitectureSpecificsMemo

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), `char` can be `signed` or `unsigned` (so you actually have two flavors of C). What exactly it is is implementation specific.

Some [processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_(computing)) and [instruction set architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) or [application binary interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) favor a `signed` character (byte) type (e.g. because it maps nicely to some [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) instruction), other favor an `unsigned` one.

`gcc` has even some `-fsigned-char` or `-funsigned-char` [option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) which you should almost never use (because changing it breaks some corner cases in [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and ABIs) unless you recompile everything, including your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library).

You could use [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) and `<endian.h>` (see [endian(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html)) or [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) on Linux to detect what your system has.

In most cases, you should write [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) C code, which does not depend upon those things. And you can find cross-platform libraries (e.g. [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/)) to help you in that.

BTW `gcc -dM -E -x c /dev/null` also gives `__BYTE_ORDER__` etc, and if you want an unsigned 8 bit byte you should use `<stdint.h>` and its `uint8_t` (more portable and more readable). And standard [limits.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) defines `CHAR_MIN` and `SCHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX` and `SCHAR_MAX` (you could compare them for equality to detect `signed char`s implementations), etc...

BTW, you should care about [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), but most systems today use [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/). Libraries like [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) are helpful. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391106/841108) and remember that practically speaking an [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) can span several bytes (i.e. `char`-s).

Comment: Of course, the easiest and most portable way to solve this problem is to just write what you mean: `signed char` or `unsigned`, as the case may be.

Answer (score 42):

The default depends on the platform and native codeset.  For example, machines that use EBCDIC (mainframes usually) must use `unsigned char` (or have `CHAR_BIT > 8`) because the C standard requires characters in the basic codeset to be positive, and EBCDIC uses codes like 240 for digit 0.  (C11 standard, §6.2.5 **Types** ¶2 says: *An object declared as type `char` is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a `char` object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative.*)

You can control which sign GCC uses with `-fsigned-char` or `-funsigned-char` options. Whether that’s a good idea is a separate discussion.

Comment: It *is* a good idea when you, as the OP is probably doing, develop and test software on a PC that is later running on a RaspberryPi.

Comment: @luator A good idea is to write code so it doesn't matter if `char` is signed or not and use `int8_t` and `uint8_t` when you need a signed or unsigned 8 bit value.

Comment: Can you point out where the C standard states that the basic codeset must be positive?

Comment: @BlackJack Okay, I agree with that.

Answer (score 13):

Character type `char` to be `signed` or `unsigned`, depending on the platform and compiler.

According to [this](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_71.html) reference link :

> The C and C++ standards allows the character type char to be **signed** or
>   **unsigned**, **depending on the platform and compiler**.
>
> Most systems, including **x86 GNU/Linux and Microsoft Windows, use signed char**,
>
> but
>   those based on **PowerPC and ARM processors typically use unsigned
>   char**.(29)
>
> This can lead to unexpected results when porting programs
>   between platforms which have different defaults for the type of char.

GCC provides the options `-fsigned-char` and `-funsigned-char` to set the default type of `char`.

Answer (score 7):

On x86-64 Linux at least, it's defined by [the x86-64 System V psABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)

Other platforms will have similar ABI standards documents that specify the rules that let different C compilers agree with each other on calling conventions, struct layouts, and stuff like that.  (See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to other x86 ABI docs, or other places for other architectures.  Most non-x86 architectures have only one or two standard ABIs.)

From the x86-64 SysV ABI:  Figure 3.1: Scalar Types

> ```
>    C            sizeof      Alignment       AMD64
>                             (bytes)         Architecture
>
> _Bool*          1             1              boolean
> -----------------------------------------------------------
> char            1             1              signed byte
> signed char
> ---------------------------------------------------------
> unsigned char   1             1              unsigned byte
> ----------------------------------------------------------
> ...
> -----------------------------------------------------------
> int             4             4              signed fourbyte
> signed int
> enum***
> -----------------------------------------------------------
> unsigned int    4             4              unsigned fourbyte
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> ...
> ```
>
> * This type is called `bool` in C++.
>
> *** C++ and some implementations of C permit enums larger than an
>   int. The underlying type is bumped to an unsigned int, long int or
>   unsigned long int, in that order.

---

Whether `char` is signed or not does actually directly affect the calling convention in this case, because of a currently-undocumented requirement which clang relies on:  [narrow types are sign or zero-extended to 32 bit when passed as function args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539), according to the callee prototype.

So for  `int foo(char c) { return c; }`, clang will rely on the *caller* to have sign-extended the arg.  ([code + asm for this and a caller on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'__attribute((noinline))%0Aint+foo(char+c)+%7B+return+c%3B+%7D%0A%0A__attribute((noinline))%0Aint+bar(char+c)+%7B+return+(unsigned+char)c%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+call_foo(unsigned+char+uc)+%7B%0A++++return+foo(uc)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:45.57133198106828,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3+-mtune%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:56.347256347256334,l:'4',m:48.484848484848484,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3+-mtune%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),l:'4',m:51.515151515151516,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:54.42866801893171,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)).

```asm
gcc:
    movsx   eax, dil       # sign-extend low byte of first arg reg into eax
    ret

clang:
    mov     eax, edi       # copy whole 32-bit reg
    ret
```

---

Even apart from the calling convention, **C compilers have to agree so they compile inline functions in a `.h` the same way.**

If `(int)(char)x` behaved differently in different compilers for the same platform, they wouldn't really be compatible.

Answer (score 6):

gcc has two compile time options that control the behaviour of `char`:

```
-funsigned-char
-fsigned-char
```

It is not recommended to use any of these options unless you know exactly what you are doing.

The default is platform-dependent and is fixed when gcc itself is built. It is chosen for best compatibility with other tools that exist on that platform.

[Source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html).

Answer (score 1):

One important practical note is that the type of a UTF-8 string literal, such as `u8"..."`, is an array of `char`, and it must be stored in UTF-8 format.  Characters in the basic set are guaranteed to be equivalent to positive integers.  However,

> If any other character is stored in a char object, the resulting value is implementation-defined but shall be within the range of values that can be represented in that type.

(In C++, the type of the UTF-8 string constant is `const char []` and it is not specified whether characters outside the basic set have numeric representations at all.)

Therefore, if your program needs to twiddle the bits of a UTF-8 string, you would need to use `unsigned char`.  Otherwise, any code that checks whether the bytes of a UTF-8 string are in a certain range will not be portable.

It’s better to explicitly cast to `unsigned char*` than to write `char` and expect the programmer to compile with the right settings to configure that as `unsigned char`.  However, you might use a `static_assert()` to test whether the range of `char` includes all the numbers from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 0):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html says

> __CHAR_UNSIGNED__
>
> GCC defines this macro if and only if the data type char is unsigned on the > target machine. It exists to cause the standard header file limits.h to work > correctly. You should not use this macro yourself; instead, refer to the
> standard macros defined in limits.h.

So it seems the reason you did not see it in your list was you were testing on a system were char is signed and the macro is not defined at all on such systems. I have confirmed it does appear in the output of `cc -dM -E -x c /dev/null | grep -i CHAR` on one of my arm systems an arm system.

The C standard leaves it up to the implementation, of course that doesn't really say much because "implementation" lumps together a bunch of things, compiler, OS, CPU architecture etc.

On Linux it depends on the CPU family. For some architectures there are or were good reasons for this. For example early arm had no real support for signed bytes. For others it seems to be more arbitrary, possibly copied from other operating systems that ran on the same hardware.

Afaict windows and mac OS use signed chars on all target architectures (or at least all that are currently supported).