# When `char` type is represented on 64 bits how can it keep its range from limits.h

Tags: c

It is possible to find architectures where the char data type is represented on 8 bytes, so 64 bits, the same as `long long` and in the same time the Standard requires the CHAR_MIN and CHAR_MAX to be bound -- see `5.2.4.2.1  Sizes of integer types <limits.h>` from the `Standard ISO 9899`.

I cannot figure out why these architectures chose to represent the char so and how does it represent char values on so a large space.  So how char values are represented in such a case ?

`sizeof(char)=1` all the time.  My question is, what is the value of `sizeof(long long)` and `sizeof(int)` on such an architecture ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is possible to find architectures where the char data type is represented on 8 bytes,

I don't know any. BTW, it is not only a matter of architecture, but also of [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). BTW, you don't define what is a byte, and the bit size of `char`-s matters much more.

<sup>(IIRC, someone coded a weird implementation of C in Common Lisp on Linux/x86-64 which has 32 bits `char`-s; of course its ABI is *not* the [usual](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) Linux one!)</sup>

> `sizeof(char)`=1 all the time. My question is, what is the value of `sizeof(long long)` and `sizeof(int)`  on such an architecture ?

It probably would be also 1 (assuming `char`, `int`, `long long` all have 64 bits) unless `long long` is e.g. 128 bits (which is possible but unusual).

Notice that the C standard imposes *minimal* bounds and bit sizes (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). E.g. `long long` could be wider than 64 bits. I never heard of such C implementations (and I hope that when 128 bits processors become common, C will be dead).

But your question is theoretical. I know no practical C implementation with 64 bits `char`-s or wider than 64 bits `long long`. In *practice* assuming that `char`-s are 8 bits (but they could be `signed` or `unsigned`, and [both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46463173/841108) exist) is a reasonable, but non universal, assumption.

Notice that C is not a universal programming language. You won't be able to code a C compiler for a ternary machine like [Setun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setun).

Comment: to be more precise, I heard about such case in the slides of the lectures of Robert Seacord, but he does not provide much details.

Comment: `unsigned long long` has a bound of ``ULLONG_MAX  = 18446744073709551615 = 2^64 − 1``... if we represent it on 128 bits how are the rest of 64 bits used ?

Comment: IIRC the standard defines *minimal* bounds. They could be greater!

Comment: no, no, it defines min and max -- pasted:  maximum value for an object of type unsigned long long int
ULLONG_MAX  18446744073709551615 // 2
64 − 1

Comment: look at `5.2.4.2.1  Sizes of integer types <limits.h>`

Comment: ``It probably would be also 1 (assuming char, int, long long all have 64 bits) unless long long is e.g. 128 bits (which is possible but unusual).``  Ok, how much is the `sizeof(int)` supposing int is represented on 24 bits in this case?

Comment: ah, it is written there -- `` Their implementation-deﬁned values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.``.. I think this statement clarifies the things a lot.

Comment: Yes, that's the one that had me scratching my head too "*Their implementation-deﬁned values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.*" Oh joy, more certainty...

Comment: I think, if char is represented on 64 then all the other types are represented on 64 bits and for each other type sizeof(T)=1.  Correct ?

Comment: I believe that 64 bits `char`s could live with 64 bits `short`-s and 128 bits `long`-s. But your question is theoretical. I hope that by the time most processors would be 128 bits the C language will be dead.

Comment: If memory serves, at least one iteration of Unix-for-Cray-supercomputers had an ABI with `CHAR_BIT==64` and `sizeof(long)==sizeof(int)==sizeof(short)==sizeof(char)==1`.  But that was a very long time ago -- possibly before C89, even.

Answer (score 4):

> It is possible to find architectures where the char data type is represented on 8 bytes

No. That's because a *char* is *defined* to be a byte *). But a byte doesn't necessarily have 8 bits. That's why the term *octet* is sometimes used to refer to a unit of 8 bits. There are architectures using more than 8 bits in a byte, but I doubt there's one with a 64bit byte, although this would be theoretically possible.

Another thing to consider is that `char` (as opposed to many other integer types) isn't allowed to have *padding bits*, so if you ever found an architecture with 64bit `char`s, that would mean `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX` would be "very large" ;)

---

*) In fact, a byte is defined to be the unit of memory used to represent an encoded character, which is normally also the smallest addressable unit of the system. 8 bits are common, The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) mentions byte sizes up to 48 bits were used. This might not be the best source, but still, finding a 64bit byte is very unlikely.

Comment: The exact-width integer types are not allowed to have padding bits either

Comment: I heard Robert Seacord saying so.  So this is possible.

Comment: @DavidBowling don't want to mention this explicitly (too far from the question), but I added a little word to clarify ;) thanks.

Comment: if `char` is represented on 48 bits and `int` on 24, what is `sizeof(int)` ?

Comment: @alinsoar that's impossible. `char` (a byte) is **always** the smallest unit.

Comment: ok, so if char is represented on 64 then all the other types are repr. on 64, such as the integer conversion rank to be sound?

Comment: in case char is represented on 32 and int is represented on 48 we will have 16 padding bits for each integer variable ?

Comment: yes, and `sizeof(int)` would still be 2 ... 48 value bits and 16 padding bits.